# How to play these grace notes and trills?

Tags: theory, piano

[image]

I have this piece from Bach called "no. 35, BWV 514" and there are these ornaments that i don't understand. Like the grace note at bar 11 where there is a eight grace note and a trill notation over the note. I know that the grace note should take half of the value of the principal note, but i don't know how to play it when the grace note has a trill mark.

Then at bar 15 there is a trill but how should it be played and end on the G note without messing the trill up.

Comment: There are plenty of recordings of this. Have you given yourself the opportunity to listen to any?

Comment: Mmmh, i haven't tried to listen to recordings of this piece. Maybe i can try to replicate how they play, thanks.

Comment: It is not always true, even in music of that period,  that the grace note takes up half the note length.

Answer (score 4):

J.S.Bach's own guide to ornaments, written for his son Wilhelm Friedemann, is 
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klavierb%C3%BCchlein_f%C3%BCr_Wilhelm_Friedemann_Bach#/media/File:Bach-ornamentguide.jpg), and there's a transcription of it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Baroque_music), which is easier to read.

Comment: Hi there!   Please paste in some quoted sections, as  links can disappear, making your answer less helpful.